# Scripting Google documents (not spreadsheets) with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

So I know that it's possible to create scripts for use on spreadsheets using Google Apps Script, but is there support for using created scripts on documents? I know that the API provides services for creating and editing documents, though they bear the experimental tag, but I can't seem to find a way to create and install a script on a document.

And when I say document services, I refer to the following link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find it because you cannot do it. Scripts can indeed manipulate documents using Document services (as you referred to) but the script itself should be linked to a spreadsheet or a Google site. Linked is probably not the best word since the apps script can be published to work as a standalone web application - in this case the link to the spreadsheet is used only during the development of your application.
I hope this makes things clear enough.

Comment: That should be enough. Thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 2):

Update: [you can do this now](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/). Just in case someone stumbles on this answer. To clarify the above answer, too: you can create scripts that are attached to documents or standalone scripts. Attached scripts can be published as add-ons, but are always associated with a document (doc, sheet, or form). Standalone scripts can be published as web apps.

Comment: Nice to see the experimental tag finally removed :)